# How to get exact time upon button click?

Tags: php, timestamp

I have this working code yet upon button click, it populate the textbox with the timestamp when the page was reloaded/loaded; What I like is for the button to populate the textbox with the time upon click. Anything that can help me will be greatly appreciated, *Cheers!*

Code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
echo    date("Y/m/d");
echo    "<br>";

$time= date("h:i:s A", strtotime("now"-8));

echo    "<input type=textfield name=time value='$time' size=9>";
echo    "<br>";
echo    "<input type=\"textfield\" id=\"textbox\" value='' size=9>";
echo    "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Time\" onClick=\"document.getElementById    ('textbox').value='$time'\">";

?>
<br>
<input id="date" name="curTime" value="<?php echo date('M d,Y'); ?>" size="9"     maxlength="10"  Required />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the actual time when the button is clicked, you will have to do that on the client side with JavaScript.

For example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Button Click</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="date" value="" />
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Get the Date!" onclick="document.getElementById('date').value = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'})" />
  </body>
</html>
```

This will populate the textarea with the current date upon click. You can send that back to your server through AJAX, POST, etc.

**Update**

Since you said you were using IE 8 and it looks like IE 8 doesn't support formatting the toLocaleString() output, you *could* filter offer the seconds with a regular expression. *I would highly recommend that you just not support IE 8 and not do the following unless you **really** have to.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Button Click</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function filter_seconds(date){
          return date.replace(/(\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2})\:\d{2}/, '$1')
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="date" value="" />
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Get the Date!" onclick="document.getElementById('date').value = filter_seconds(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language))" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works but it prints the date, what will I change to be able to get the time? and How will I use this script to put the output in a textbox?

Comment: What type of "time" do you want? Something like "12:23 PM"?

Comment: Yes, just hour, minute, and AM/PM.

Comment: I have updated the example for what you requested. It now gets the Date in locale time and puts that value in a `<textarea>`.

I would suggest the Mozilla Developer Network for looking up API info for functions and standard library classes. Here is the MDN link for the method I used (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString).

Comment: Is there a way to remove the seconds or modify the format? and if I change the location of the output to a textbox, would I just add the textbox and use its name on your code? Ex. change "date" to ex."time"?

Comment: You can use the options argument, outlined in the link in my previous comment, to change the date representation. I have updated the example to remove seconds using this method.

The `id` attribute is what the JavaScript code is using to locate the proper element and update it's HTML, so as long as it is consistent between the assignment in `onclick` and the attribute `<textarea>`, then everything will be fine.

Comment: I tried your updated answer, but unfortunately it did not printed just hours and minutes. I tried adding/changing the code from textarea to a textbox using <input type="textfield" id=textbox value='' size=6> and referred unto it with your code using the id "textbox" yet it doesn't work.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken I think what you want is `<input type="text"/>` not `<input type="textfield" />`.

I have update the example to use the `<input type="text" />`

I have tested the above example in Firefox, Chrome, and IE and it renders without seconds. What browser/version are you using?

Comment: Apologies for the textfield problem; I am using IE8 and it still prints seconds. But overall, your answer is working and I am grateful, more power!

Comment: I added a method that *should* work in IE 8 to remove seconds (I don't have a copy so I can't test it). I would recommend that you **not** use it unless you **really** have to.